# no module named rospy after anaconda install

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, rospy, module, anaconda

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,

I was using ros kinetic with py scipts without problem, but then I tried installing Anaconda 3.5 and all my ROS is messed as you guess. So I uninstalled Anaconda 3.5 and installed Anaconda 2.7.

Now the problem is I cannot run py scripts, as they usually give error like ImportError: no module named 'rospy' and etc..

when I tried

```
which python
```

it shows me `/usr/bin/python` that I believe it is wrong

```
python --version
```

shows Python 2.7.12

I tried adding `export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-package` without comment but it didn't work.

where I am doing wrong? could you help me thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/311797/no-module-named-rospy-after-anaconda-install/) by [OsManiaC](https://answers.ros.org/users/38586/osmaniac/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2019-01-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Anaconda has probably installed a new version of python and more importantly updated the `PYTHONPATH` so that it no longer includes the path of the required ROS packages. You should be able to add the necessary path back in by adding a line to your `.bashrc` file.

Your `PYTHONPATH` envrionment variable should include a path to /opt/ros/<ros_version>/lib/python2.7/dist-packages, if it doesn't then this may be the cause of your problem. You can check this with the following command:

```
printenv PYTHONPATH
```

If you add `export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/opt/ros/<ros_version>/lib/python2.7/dist-packages` to your bashrc file and re-run it then this should hopefully fix your problem.

---

Originally posted by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) with karma: 9529 on 2019-01-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-01-03**:\

> updated the `PYTHONPATH` so that it no longer includes the path of the required ROS packages. You should be able to add the necessary path back in by adding a line to your `.bashrc` file.

Note: `source`ing `setup.bash` should setup `PYTHONPATH` for you. I'm not sure about Anaconda, but ..

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-01-03**:
.. manually changing `PYTHONPATH` through `.bashrc` should be done with care, and only if/when absolutely necessary.

Not saying it shouldn't be done in this case, just wanted to add a bit of "don't touch this willy-nilly".